# Opensearch Reindex with Date field format change

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch, spring-boot-3

**We are migrating from ElasticSearch-client(4) to Opensearch-client 1.3 (which intenally uses ElasticSearch-client 5)**.

New ElasticSearch 5 (internally used by opensearch 1.3), the `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.DateFormat.custom` is deprecated and is no longer available.
Planning to change from `DateFormat.custom` to `DateFormat.date_hour_minute_second_millis`

In my Index I have an **old field**

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "MM-dd-uuuu'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-uuuu'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private LocalDateTime eventDateTime;
```

Planning to change this field to a new field -

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date_hour_minute_second_millis, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
@JsonFormat(pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
private LocalDateTime eventDateTime;
```

So,

1. **Question 1** - I guess reindexing is only the option as i cannot lose the old data.
2. **Question 2** - If Reindexing is the option, how can i achieve this using opensearch high rest client? Any sample code would help.